# How to make a method from a string(Text) WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, string, visual-studio

I'm new in programing in WPF and I'm working on an application that uses AvalonEdit to make a script and get a string like this:

```
  "Task1Init
       Do Function1 (Argument 1)
       Do Function2 (Argument 2)
       Do Function3 (Argument 3)
   End"
```

Then I modify the string and get a Method like this:

```
"public void Task1(){
     Function1(A1);
     Function2(A2);
     Function3(A3);
}"
```

In this case all the functions are defined in a file AviliableFunctions.cs.

If I want to Run the Task1(), What will be the best way to convert the String into C# Code?, I have been searching and found the tool roslyn, but I'm not sure if it can be used to do this.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to execute and/or convert some string that contains some kind of script, right? So, the problem is not about WPF, or am i mistaken? (Where you get the "script" string from is not part of your problem you are asking here about, correct?)

Comment: Yes, where I get the "Script" its not the problem, the problem its how to run it.